# Android: Web App Works in Chrome, but not Webview

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, google-chrome, webview

I am using `ng-hide` and `ng-show` in my web app to handle what gets displayed based on the user's login status. This works completely fine if I go to the Chrome browser on my phone and run the site.

However, when I try to display it in a webview on my app or on the default phone non-Chrome browser, it does not work. None of the contents are hidden and the buttons which are binded to angularJS functions do not work. Note that I do have `setJavaScriptEnabled(true)` set.

When I looked this issue up, I noticed that some AngularJS features do not work on certain browsers (especially IE), thus it may be possible that AngularJS is incompatible with the default Webview. So is there a workaround or some way for me to make the webview emulate the Chrome browser?

App on Chrome Browser: http://gyazo.com/8a8a56bdac1eb7e91753bc4745433a42
App on Webview: http://gyazo.com/a58de6192aa822af05a2885560e66f91

There are the following errors in the logcat, which I have investigated and make no sense since both variables have no issues in non-webview environments.

> E/Web Console﹕ Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier:103
>   E/Web Console﹕: Uncaught Error: No module: AuthApp:17

The uncaught syntax error corresponds to the below, where results is the query results I am getting from Parse. Note that I have checked the contents of results in other browsers and it is in fact returning the results to my query.

```
 for (var result of results){
...
}
```

Comment: Can you share non-sensitive information from your manifest.json? Also post any errors you are receiving in the console log when loading the app. A screenshot of the app inside and outside of a webview will also be helpful.

Answer (score 10):

try these settings on your webview. i have had success in the past with these

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

Comment: No luck. The angularJS stuff still isn't working after adding these settings.

Comment: webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true) and 
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true) did the trick for angularjs based website .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can add these lines, it will fix your issue

```
when {
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21 -> {
            binding.webView.settings.mixedContentMode = 0
            binding.webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null)
        }
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19 -> {
            binding.webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null)
        }
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19 -> {
            binding.webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)
        }
    }
```